Comparing Logistic Regressions - Exact Same Parameters and Sample - Different Operational Definition for 1 Categorical Parameter
Context: I have two models with the exact same structure and sample data, but one of the binary predictors (binary.pred.2) is defined using a different algorithm in each model.

Model 1: binary outcome ~ binary.pred.1 + binary.pred.2 (definition A) + continuous.pred.1
Model 2: binary outcome ~ binary.pred.1 + binary.pred.2 (definition B) + continuous.pred.1

I'm using AUC/ROC, AIC, RMSE, and McFadden's Pseudo R-square statistics to compare the models, but I also want an actual hypothesis test. I landed on Wilks' likelihood ratio test (LRT), but I will also be exploring the appropriateness of the Wald and Lagrange Multiplier tests.
Question: Even though Model 2 is not a nested version of Model 1, can I still use LRT to evaluate the hypothesis that each models' likelihood ratio is significantly different?
